# A call to "sys.sp_procedure_params_100_managed" system stored procedure in SQL Server doesn't return data for an application role

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, enterprise-library

I have a .NET app which connects to SQL Server 2012 database. The app uses a SQL Server application role which has execute permissions only on the stored procedures in the database. The app uses Enterprise Library which uses the `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` method.

This method calls the `[sys].[sp_procedure_params_100_managed]` system procedure. The call to this procedure returns no results which is an error and causes EL to give a "Stored procedure xx doesn't exist". XX is the parameter, a procedure name, to the `sp_procedure_params_100_managed` system procedure to get the input procedure's parameters info. If I do the same call using a user with  higher SQL Server privileges, the procedure returns data. So the no data for the application role seems to be a permission/privilege issue.

How does one give proper permissions to a specific system procedure to an application role?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Master;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_procedure_params_100_managed]
    TO ApplicationUser;  --<-- Whatever the Application Use is called
GO
```

Comment: The application role is defined in a specific database only. It's not visible in master. I get "cannot find the user 'xx'..." Also I am not sure about the grant execute. The app role doesn't get execute denied error, unless the grant adds the proper permissions.

Comment: Replace 'USE Master' with 'USE MyDataBase'

Answer (score 0):

```
Use MyDatabase;
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::[sys].[sp_procedure_params_100_managed]
    TO ApplicationUser;  --<-- Whatever the Application User is called
GO
```

Cribbing from M.Ali.

The **likely** reason for the failure is because you have granted EXECUTE rights on the stored procedures in the **DBO** schema, where **SYS** is actually a separate schema.   That's difficult to tell without your providing the actual user account configuration though.

Answer (score 0):

use YOURDB;
go
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO YOURUSER

-- that worked for me.  I was not getting a permissions error - instead, no rows were returned before granting view definition.